# Java Signature: private key and certificate validation fails

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature, sha256

I'm trying to sign and then verify data with RSA-SHA256, a private key and a certificate:

PrivateKey is the private key

PublicKey comes from cert via cert.getPublicKey();

```
protected String sign(String plainText, PrivateKey privateKey, PublicKey publicKey, java.security.cert.Certificate certificate) throws Exception {
        //Sign
        Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        privateSignature.initSign(privateKey);
        privateSignature.update(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();
        String result = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
        //Verify
        privateSignature.initVerify(publicKey);
        privateSignature.update(signature);
        boolean bool = privateSignature.verify(signature);
        System.out.println("VERIFIED: "+bool); //Always false
        return result;
    }
```

Problem is, I always get false.

Even though I tested the same certificate and private key on here:

https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html

And it says my private key and certificate matches.

What is the problem here?

Comment: In the `update` call of the verification part the plaintext, i.e. `plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`, must be passed instead of `signature`. Then the verification is successful.

Comment: Thanks, actually noticed that too, solved it